# My function output has wrong format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a function which returns abnormal output - I call the function below:

```
def gWord(s):
    tessr = []
    for line in s :
       if(Character(line)==True):
             tessr.append(line)
       if(Character(line)==False):
             if((line)=="'"):
                   tessr.append(line)                     
 return(print(tessr))
gWord("  !,Nord's**  ")
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
['N', 'o', 'r', 'd', "'", 's']
```

I want to get just this:

```
Nord's
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So why are you using list?

Comment: Why don't you just use `if Character(line):` and `else:`? What is a `Character`?

Comment: Appending items to a list separates them by comma. Thus, you are appending the individual characters of the word to the list, not the word itself. As someone has mentioned before, you should create a target string and append characters to it. Or, you could still use the list and join it.

Comment: Can you explain what `Character()` is? There is probably a much simpler way to write this with `string.replace()` But I don't know the criteria you're using to determine which characters to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output it not abnormal because `tessr` is a list. You want `tessr` to be a `str` so you want

```
tessr = ""
```

Then you can append the characters to the `str` with

```
tessr += line
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Character checks the same as isalpha method, you can use it like this which seems to me the approach.

Please notice that you don't have to compare `if(Character(line)==True)`, you can simply write `if(Character(line))` they have the same meaning.

Also, python standard is to start methods with lower case (`Character() -> character`)

```
def gWord(s):
    tessr = "".join([ch for ch in s if character(ch) or ch =="'"])
    print (tessr)
gWord("  !,Nord's**  ")
```